# What test should I use to compare 2 group with very similar characteristic?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, anomaly-detection, fraud-detection

I am currenty doing a fraud detection analysis. I have 2 groups of data points with several features that I create myself. 1 group is fraud people and another group is non fraud.

I found out that the features are mostly similar between the 2 groups that it is hard to distinguish the group based on these features. If I map the datapoint in 2D space, the points are overlapping. There is still very slight difference we can observe between the features.

My main objective is to find a feature that best distinguish the 2 groups. Is there any test that I can use to support my hypothesis for this problem? Or is there any other statistical approach I can use for this problem?

Sorry for the very general question. I am just starting in the field of statistics. I tried to make it more specific with questions I got from you.

Comment: SVM could solve this with an appropriate kernel (not easy).

Comment: let me see if my understanding is correct. SVM is a machine learning algorithm used for prediction & classification. How is SVM useful in looking most distinguishing feature?

Comment: Lots of machine learning algorithms estimate feature importances, for SVM look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2179/variable-importance-from-svm